# Adding padding to backgroundcolorspan

Tags: android

How do you add padding to a backgroundcolorspan I have looked at the properties but nothing is jumping out at me. At this stage the only way I can see it work is creating a custom view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Define a `Shape` (a rectangle one specifically) and then assign this shape as background of your view, you can customize it to your needs like adding rounded corners etc.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: Hi. This will not have the same effect as the background span where only the text has a background and not the whole view.

Comment: then just apply this only to your textview?

Comment: Hi. If you apply a background to the textview it will fill the whole textview so if it say white it will be a white block with text on top.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom control.Where i use the lovely paint methods to get what i am looking for.

Comment: Hey. I am looking to achieve a similar effect. Can you elaborate how you solved this problem?